# acceder a 1 objeto de un array de localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Necesito acceder 1 a 1 a los datos del localstorage y al hacer console.log no logro acceder a solo 1 dato, si a todos a la vez del dejo el codigo donde los pongo en el localstorage y los trato de traer

es un evento en un boton que guarda los datos de perfil de usuario

```
document.getElementById("actualize").addEventListener("click",()=>{

        
    
    let dataList;
    const lsUser = {
        name: document.getElementById('name').value,
        secondName: document.getElementById('second-name').value,
        surname: document.getElementById('surname').value,
        secondSurname: document.getElementById('second-surname').value,
        email: document.getElementById('email').value,
        phone: document.getElementById('phone').value
    };
    
    dataList = [];
    
    dataList.push(lsUser);
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(dataList));
    
    
        
});

console.log(localStorage.getItem(('userData')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongamos que queremos acceder a solo 1 elemento del array guardado en el LocalStorage, podemos agregar un elemento (no pusiste tu HTML por cierto) que al hacer click me muestre cierto elemento en ese array:

```
<div id="getdata">Get Data from LS</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("getdata").addEventListener("click",() => {
   console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(('userData')))[2]) // asi accedemos al tercer elemento del array del localstorage
})
```

Esto siempre y cuando ese elemento exista, al momento de hacer click puede que no se haya agregado nada en el índice buscado, o que se haya vaciado la LocalStorage en ese caso ten en cuenta que no nos tirara un error de tipo "indice excede el tamaño del array", sino que mostrara simplemente `undefined` al intentar imprimir el dato. Intenta agrega todo tu código que sino es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias soy nuevo con esto del localstorage :D